# How to add two Firebase Project in one Android App

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I am building an app for the company. I have requirement for maintaining 2 firebase analytics for the same app.i.e. I have a UAT environment and a Production environment.

I want to see how the app is performing in the UAT alone. Currently the project is receiving data from both UAT and Production at same time. The senior testing team needed to see this in 2 different projects within Firebase for UAT and Prod.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Each Android app can only report its crashes to Crashlytics in a single Firebase project. There is no way to report crashes to multiple projects in one app install.

---

That said, it sounds like you "just" want to be able to report to a different project for different (prod/UAT) builds of your app. If so, that can be accomplished by including a different `google-services.json` for each of those build flavors.

With that, each build uses a different project, but each build still only uses one project. To learn how to set this up, check [using multiple environments in your Android application](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#support_multiple_environments_in_your_android_application) in the Firebase documentation.